# "This system cannot be solved with the methods available to Solve" What should be done in such case?

Tags: equation-solving

What can I do to solve this task?

```
Solve[Power[x, 2] + Power[y, 2] + 1 == cos[Power[x, 2]*Power[y, 2]], {x, 
  y}]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Reduce[Power[x, 2] + Power[y, 2] + 1 == 
  Cos[Power[x, 2]*Power[y, 2]], {x, y}, Reals]
```

> x==0&&y==0

Comment: thank you! Cheers

Comment: Also, `Solve[Power[x, 2] + Power[y, 2] + 1 == 
  Cos[Power[x, 2]*Power[y, 2]], {x, y}, Reals, Method -> Reduce]`